# Is it possible to view a Java class files bytecode

Tags: java, bytecode

I am working on a bytecode manipulation/generation in Java and I was just wondering if there is an easy way I could check the bytecode.  I do not want to decompile the file, I would like to actually look at the compiled bytecode.  I do not need to edit it.  Any links or programs for doing this would be acceptable answers.

Comment: You can normally do it directly from within your IDE. Maybe with a little help from a plugin.

Comment: I think `javap` is what you are looking for. A command that comes with the JDK.

Comment: try javap -c classfile

Comment: no that doesnt show all bytecode only field and methods

Comment: @Popgalop `javap -v` shows the bytecode - see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been working on a [decompiler](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/wiki/Java%20Decompiler) that has a color-coded bytecode output mode (which I find far more readable than javap).  It can also output Java code or an intermediate 'bytecode AST'.

Answer (score 48):

Since you wanted to be guided to some program that can easily show you the byte code then my suggestion is to use IntelliJ IDEA since it has built-in support for viewing byte code.

Here's an example how to do it (it can also be mapped to some keys of your choice):

[image]

[image]

It is very easy, and it can surely be done in eclipse or NetBeans as well.

Comment: where's line numbers? What are L0,L1.. mean ????

Comment: Is this also available in Android studio? At least for classes compield for the JVM (like local Unit Tests etc).

Comment: @PSIXO I don't know, I only use IntelliJ as-is.

Comment: note that this requires the _ByteCode Viewer_ plugin

Comment: @voipp `LINENUMBER 10 L2` means that the code on line number 10 is located at label `L2`. So `L0`, `L1` etc are labels, i.e. jump points in your program. In bytecode there are no functions or loops, there are only jumps (which can be conditional). So the whole program is a bunch of `IF this GO there_1; IF that GO there_2`

Comment: `javap -c` outputs something completely different, something much simpler. Is there a way to view that as well?

Answer (score 6):

Not sure what exactly you need, but apart from [`javap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html), which is a command-line tool for displaying the bytecode, you can take a look at [javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/), [asm](http://asm.ow2.org/) and [cglib](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) - they allow you to parse the bytecode with java code.

Answer (score 2):

[The `javap` command-line tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html), which is bundled with Oracle's JDK, gives a detailed textual dump of .class files along with the constant pool and all functions' bytecode content. Just run it with `-v` to get a full dump.

Comment: but i want to see what the compiler reads when it reads the file so that i can create my own synthetic classes.

Comment: @Popgalop what the compiler reads in is the actual bytecode, which is not a textual format. I guess you could open it in a hex editor and use [this reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/ClassFile.doc.html) to parse it by yourself, but if you want a human-readable dump, `javap -v` is the answer.